# Binding WPF Controls to a WCF Service

Tags: wpf, wcf, wcf-binding

I want to know how to bind WPF controls to a WCF Service, I only find references to bind to a WCF Data Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first make a call to access data from the service. See [this introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx) for how to do that. (It sounds like you already have an existing service so you will just need to consume it.) Once you have successfully retrieved data from the service you can set the data context of your view (I assume you are using vanilla WPF without an MVVM setup since this question is basic) and bind to the data.

---

Edit: Here is [a tutorial](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/09/wcf-service-and-wpf-client-datagrid.html#.UzwUI_kRDds) describing what you need.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm studying wcf, I want to build a wpf app that two way binds its controls to a viw model which in turn binds it's properties to a wcf service. But I start with the basics. BTW, I know how to retrieve data, but how do I set the context from a wcf service?. For Data Services I see that they do something like new dataContext(new Uri("<Service address>")), but with a complete WCF Service I don't know. If you know of a page that explains it all to me (two way binding wpf controls to a view model which in turn are bound to a wcf service), I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out.